# Elastic Beanstalk fails to deploy my React.js app code via CodePipeline

Tags: reactjs, node.js, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

While deploying my code via CodePipeline, I am getting below error and deployment stage gets failed

Deployment completed, but with errors: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version. Failed to deploy application. Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-instanceid121212'. Aborting the operation.

Please somebody help. I checked logs and it only returns this error. While trying to retrieve logs from elasticbeanstalk it returns "Failed to retrieve logs".

I tried all ways but not getting it's solution. I want to deploy my react.js code via CodePipeline to ElasticBeanstalk.